# Write $(7,\omega -5)$ as principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, normed-spaces, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the number ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, then
$$\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} \right]=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$$
I am told that $\mathcal{O}$ is a PID. I have factorized the ideal $7\mathcal{O}$ as follows:
$$7\mathcal{O}=(7, \omega -5)(7, \omega -3)$$
However, as $\mathcal{O}$ is a PID I would like to express both of these ideals as principal ideals. I know from the factorisation of $7\mathcal{O}$ that both $(7, \omega -5)$ and $(7, \omega -3)$ must have norm $7$. Therefore I just have to look up for an element with norm $7$ (the norm of a principal ideal is the norm of its generator).

Let $\alpha=x+y\omega$, $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$N(\alpha)=x^2-y^2\omega^2=x^2-y^2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2} \right)=7$$
$$2x^2+y^2-y^2\sqrt{-3}=7$$
However, this doesn't have any solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $N(\alpha)=\alpha\bar\alpha=(x+y\omega)(x+y\bar\omega)=x^2 + x y + y^2$. Sorry for the noise

Comment: @lhf that is exactly what i was trying to do, maybe I made a mistake in my calculations

Comment: $\overline{\omega}$ is not equal to $-\omega$. Instead wwe have $\overline{\omega}=-\omega-1$, and therefore $N(\alpha)=x^2-xy+y^2$.

Comment: Oops. I'm used too calling the third root of unity $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$. This explains the difference in the formulas for the norm in lhf's and my comments.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know. I am not sayint that $\overline{\omega}$ is $-\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. i am saying it is $\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: But
$$N(\alpha)=(x+y\omega)(x+y\overline{\omega})=x^2+xy(\omega+\overline{\omega})+y^2\omega\overline{\omega}.$$ You still have $\omega\overline{\omega}=1$, but
this time $\omega+\overline{\omega}\neq0$.

Comment: You seem to have calculated as if $x+y\overline{\omega}=x-y\omega$. How else would you have arrived at the wrong formula $N(\alpha)=x^2-y^2\omega^2$? That is why I emphasized the fact $\overline{\omega}\neq -\omega$.